# How are the coefficients of a Bloch wave defined?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, schroedinger-equation

In the 1-Dim nearly free electron model with Born-von karman boundary conditions, we manage to determine that the energy eigenfunctions are of the form

$$\psi_k(x)=\sum_{G}C(k-G)e^{i(k-G)x} \tag{1}$$
where $k=n2\pi/Na$ and the sum runs over all the reciprocal lattice vectors $G$. In order to derive this result, we take advantage of the lattice periodicity of the potential energy and hence write the potential as a Fourier series

$$U(x)=\sum_G U_G e^{iGx}\tag{2}$$
where as usual, the Fourier coefficients are $U_G=\frac{1}{a}\int_{-a/2}^{a/2}U(x)e^{-iGx}dx$. We also write the initial wave function in the form
$$\psi(x)=\sum_k C(k)e^{ikx}\tag{3}$$
Then by subbing equations 2 and 3 into the Schrodinger equation we get the result in equation (1). My question is this: what form do the coefficients C(k) in eq 2 take ? The coefficients U_G
are genuine Fourier coefficients defined in the usual way as mentioned above. Are the C(k) also genuine Fourier coefficients so that $C(k)=\frac{1}{Na}\int_{-Na/2}^{Na/2}\psi(x)e^{-ikx}dx$ or are they initially assumed to simply be arbitrary coefficients subject only to the constraint that the resulting sum in equation (2) is normalizable?

Comment: Have you tried your ansatz?

Comment: @Jakob do you mean by substituting $C(k)=\frac{1}{Na}\int_{-Na/2}^{Na/2}\psi(x)e^{-ikx}dx$ into eq 3 and then  plugging the resulting expression into the schrodinger eq?

Comment: I thought your question was to obtain an expression for the $C(k)$? Then your ansatz would be to integrate $\psi(x) e^{-ikx}$ with a suitable normalization. Have you tried that? Further, note that in bra-ket notation $ \displaystyle |\psi\rangle  = \sum\limits_n c_n |n\rangle$ for some orthonormal basis $|n\rangle$. Now how do you obtain an expression for $c_n$ in terms of $|\psi\rangle$ and $|n\rangle$...?

Comment: Okay I see where you coming from. For your last case, it would be $c_n=\langle n |\psi \rangle$ and for the ansatz it would be $c(k)=\int e^{-ikx}\psi(x)dx$ where the integral is over the full volume of the solid. So if I understand correctly, equation 3 is simply an ansatz that assumes $\psi$ to be some as-yet-unknown linear combination of the complete basis set {$Ae^{ikx}$}, where the {$c(k)$} must just be such that $\psi$ is normalizable. That is, equation 3 is logically identical to $|\psi\rangle  = \sum\limits_n c_n |n\rangle$ with {$| n \rangle$}={$e^{ikx}$}

Comment: You can answer your own question if you want to. This could help future readers.